# How to solve a wrongly done ordening at the creation of a new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, create-table

I'm trying to create a new table from a sub table, getting data from one row and turning it into a single ordered column, using the following example:

```
create table if not exists `new_table` as
    select * from (
        select descrip,
        max(case when ID = 1.01 then value else 0 end) 'column'
        from(
            select ID, `JUL-08` value, '1' descrip 
            from original_table
            union all
            select ID, `AUG-08` value, '2' descrip
            from original_table
            union all
            select ID, `SEP-08` value, '3' descrip
            from original_table
            union all
            select ID, `OCT-08` value, '4' descrip 
            from original_table
            union all
            select ID, `NOV-08` value, '5' descrip 
            from original_table
            union all
            select ID, `DEC-08` value, '6' descrip 
            from original_table
        ) src
        group by descrip
    ) as `new_table`;
```

At first it works pretty well, when I ask the table to show the data, it is there. But when I use this model to create a table of over 10 columns, the `descrip` column gets disordered.

With this example above, the order of the values in the `descrip` column are shown when using `order by descrip` is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
```

But if i use this same example to create a table with 20 rows, the `order by` of the numbers in the `descrip` column will be like:

```
1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
```

Why is that happening and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the data type of `descrip` and looks like varchar. If so then do `order by descrip+0`

Comment: You have put single quotes around `descrip` so it is a string.  Strings get sorted as strings.  If you want them to be ordered like a number, then remove the single quotes and be sure the destination column is numeric.

Comment: I dropped the table and corrected the formula taking the ' ' from the numeric values in the descrip collumn, making it a collumn of int values.